# python pip may not be installed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm not entirely confident I have pip installed correctly, because it is in my \Scripts folder, but when I try to use pip to install a library, it says pip is not installed correctly.

To make sure I have python installed, I used the following:

```
M:\M\embedPy_windows-1.5.0>where python
C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe
```

In my C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts folder, I have the following libraries installed:

```
normalizer.exe
pip.exe
ppip3.9.exe
pip3.10.exe
pip3.exe
wheel.exe
```

I also added this folder to the Path variable in Environment Variables:
C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
...

My PYTHONPATH variable looks like this: C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib

My PYTHON_HOME variable looks like this: C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

I think I have my environment set up correctly, however, when I try to run a script, I get an error that a library is missing, and then when I try to install the library, it looks like it's already installed:

```
'libpython
  [5]  M:\M\embedPy_windows-1.5.0\p.q:14:
 .P.env:not H~P;
 .p:(`:./p 2:(`init;3))[L;H;B]]
    ^
```

```
M:\M\embedPy_windows-1.5.0>python -m pip install libpython
Requirement already satisfied: libpython in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from libpython) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->libpython) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->libpython) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->libpython) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\a623\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->libpython) (2024.2.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm a little lost on what to do, does anyone have any suggestions as to what to do?

Comment: Did you try updating the pip  using 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' ? I would rather go for a clean installation and make sure when you install python/libraries you are running the shell as admin to avoid any permission issues.

Comment: I just did, unfortunately I get the same error. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Another thing I would do is to give a path that is directly under c:\ drive and not under users. I have had faced issues when the folders were under user's folder. Also your error does not say that libpython is missing.  Which specific library are you using and which statement is causing the error ? Are you able to run simple vanilla python code ? Also what is M DRIVE  ?  Is it just another hard drive partition ?

Comment: I'm not using a library, strangely though the code is highlighting ```'libpython``` as the error. The M: drive is a separate partition of the hard drive. I might try uninstalling python and reinstalling so it's in the C: drive